# Conditional Drill Down Powerview

Tags: powerpivot, dax, powerview

Not sure if this is doable but I just wonder say if my data set got this structure

Department, Team, Service, Area

and I got a measure lets call it #count that count all rows in this table.

When create a powerview chart I want to be able to drill down by Department, Team, Service and Area.

However if say in Area there are following attributes

Area 1 - 10 rows
Area 2 - 5 rows
Area 3  - 3 rows

Is it possible to stop drill down if count row in certain area is less than 5 per se?

Appreciate all advice.
Many thanks

Peddie